# Spacebar not launching application / open file

Tags: shortcut-keys

I remember on Ubuntu 10.04 you could mark a file, lets say a picture and then hit the <kbd>Space</kbd> key, this would open the picture.

I think after Ubuntu 10.10 this doesn't work. How can I make again the <kbd>Space</kbd> to work as <kbd>Enter</kbd>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can, but shift+space will open the selected file.

The reason I don't think you can do what you asked is that it is simply not listed as an option, and you wouldn't want to remap the space key because you would no longer be able to enter a space.

On my 10.04 system (Gnome), it works the same way.  Perhaps it changed on an update, but I don't know that it ever worked that way.  I wouldn't expect it to.

Comment: Well it was working the same way as on Mac OS.
Shift+Space fits my needs. I just didn't know this combination. Answer accepted! Thanks!